# What's the difference between ethers.provider and ethers.network.provider in ethers.js?

Tags: testing, hardhat, ethers.js

I am using hardhat and ethers.js for testing and when I call

```
WETHSigner = await ethers.provider.getSigner(WETHHolderAddress);
```

it fails but this works:

```
WETHSigner = await ethers.getSigner(WETHHolderAddress);
```

Can someone explain with an example between a provider and a network?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers` plugin, the `ethers` object in the [Hardhat Runtime Environment](https://hardhat.org/advanced/hardhat-runtime-environment.html) has a couple of extra properties added:

- `ethers.provider` is an ethers [provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/provider/-%23-Provider) connected to the chosen network. So if you run a script with, for example, `hh run script.js --network localhost`, then `ethers.provider` will be connected to `http://localhost:8545`. You can use it as any ethers provider, and call methods like `ethers.provider.getBlockNumber`.
- Some helper methods are also added, like `ethers.getSigner` or `ethers.getContractFactory`. You can check the full list in the [plugin's docs](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers.html).

Besides this, you also have the rest of the properties/methods exposed by ethers itself, like `ethers.utils`.

With respect to the difference between `ethers.getSigner` and `ethers.provider.getSigner`, they are pretty much equivalent, except for two things:

- `ethers.getSigner` returns a promise, while `ethers.provider.getSigner` don't. That is, you need to use `await` in the first case.
- The Signer returned by `ethers.getSigner` is a wrapper created by the plugin that behaves pretty much exactly like the one returned by `ethers.provider.getSigner`, except that it has a `.address` property, so you don't need to call `signer.getAddress()`, which is an async function.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! But What's the difference between `ethers.provider.getSigner` and `ethers.getSigner` ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that that was the main point of your question. I actually don't know why the first case fails for you, so you should expand on that. As I explained in the (edited) answer, they are pretty much the same thing, except for the two differences I explained.